# connecting to magento api using soap java

Tags: java, magento, soap

magento api using soap doesn't work due to missing magento-api.properties files, can someone help?

```
public class testConnection {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AxisFault {
        String user = "rajeshvishnani";
        String pass = "123456";
        String host = "http://cypherincorporated.co.in/magento/index.php/api/soap?wsdl";

        SoapConfig soapConfig = new SoapConfig(user, pass, host);
        MagentoSoapClient magentoSoapClient = MagentoSoapClient.getInstance(soapConfig);        
        magentoSoapClient.setConfig(soapConfig);

    }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: could not load [magento-api.properties] as a classloader resource
    at com.google.code.magja.utils.PropertyLoader.loadProperties(PropertyLoader.java:106)
    at com.google.code.magja.utils.PropertyLoader.loadProperties(PropertyLoader.java:123)
    at com.google.code.magja.soap.MagentoSoapClient.getInstance(MagentoSoapClient.java:69)
    at magentomanager.testConnection.main(testConnection.java:15)
```

Comment: what is magento in your  site url http://cypherincorporated.co.in/magento/.? Is this a magento directory? Please explain more what do you want to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the url to `'http://yoursite.com/api/v2_soap/index?wsdl=1'.`

Please provide more details. 
Not sure about java exception but you can try following link.
[Link](https://code.google.com/p/magja/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/google/code/magja/soap/MagentoSoapClient.java?r=321)